# Powershell: Scheduled task running script in background instead of foreground

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I am using windows "scheduled tasks" to run a powershell script with parameters.

For some reason it is executing in the background rather than the foreground.  I want to be able to see it executing... it takes over 1 hour to finish and I want to watch its progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two possible reasons that I can think of:

- "Run whether user is logged on or not" option selected
- paramete -WindowStyle Hidden on powershell.exe specified.

If neither is the case, than I don't know what may be the reason. Maybe some other script element that hides PowerShell window?

Comment: Ahh... yes, it was the "Run whether user is logged on or not" flag.  As soon as I turned that off and re-run the task I saw the Powershell window pop open and run in the foreground!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Is it Windows Server or Windows 7 machine?

In Windows Sever task scheduler launches application in no user mode (unless specified in policy) versus, Windows 7 the scheduler launching application in system account. This could be reason for Windows is hidden.

Also if you script take an hour to run showing PS window is not a great idea, instead you can route your PS output to a text file and check the file details to monitor the progress when needed.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good suggestion.  I think I will output to a file and monitor that.